# Event not firing when running as service

Tags: c#, events, service, delegates

I have an Event that works just fine when running in test mode, but does not fire when I run the code as a service. Before I post the code, let me give a bit of structure for the application, as I feel this is where the problem is stemming.

I have a tray app that is used to control a router service. When started, the service loads a dll library where all the processing takes place. When the library is started, it scans a directory for plug-ins, and hooks them into the main program.

When built as Release, the service is activated, and I have to install the application. As a side note, the tray app is run as administrator so it can control the service. When building as Debug, the tray starts the library dll directly, skipping the small service app that starts it. See the diagram below:

[image]

In either case, the flow for this plugin is a Receiver receives a file, and notifies a Sender to forward it through an Event. The file is sent off for remote processing, and then returned to another Receiver, which forwards the results to the plugin through an Event. The plugin then processes the file, and should send back to the main program in an Event. When running in Debug (no service), this is exactly what happens. When running as a service, all the Event handling works perfectly except for the plugin notifying the main program that the results were processed. There are no exceptions thrown, and I have confirmed through logging that the Event was hooked up correctly.

Connecting the Event:

```
//  Connect delegate to plugins that will add data to the database through the Router
if (plugin is INotify)
{
    ((INotify)plugin).NotifyProcessingComplete += new ProcessNotification(this.OnProcessed);
    LogWriter.Log("Associated " + plugin.Name + " with OnProcessed", LogFile);
}
```

Calling the Event from the plugin:

```
if (NotifyProcessingComplete != null)
    NotifyProcessingComplete(ExtractResults(args.ReceivedFile));
else
    LogWriter.Log("NotifyProcessingComplete Delegate was null.", LogFile);
```

Event Handler:

```
public void OnProcessed(ProcessArgs args)
{
    LogWriter.Log("On Dicom Process was called...", LogFile);
    lock (threadLock)
    {
        if (Settings != null)
        { ... }
    }
}
```

According to the logs, the plugin is hooked up correctly to OnProcessed, and logging in the ExtractResults() method shows that it is returning correctly. However, NotifyProcessingComplete is not calling the OnProcessed method.

Once again, this is only happening when running the code as a service. I suspect it may have something to do with the tray running as administrator, the service running as Local System, and the plugin being dynamically loaded.

Below I have included my code for loading a plugin, in case it might help:

```
private void loadPlugins()
{
    String pluginPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    //  Create a domain to text for plugins
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("PluginLoader");

    PluginFinder finder = (PluginFinder)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
        typeof(PluginFinder).Assembly.FullName, typeof(PluginFinder).FullName);
    finder.LogFile = logFile;

    //  Get valid plugins, and then unload the domain to clear up memory
    List<String> FoundPluginTypes = finder.SearchPath(pluginPath);
    AppDomain.Unload(domain);

    //  Load the plugins
    Plugins = new List<IPlugin>();
    foreach (String plugin in FoundPluginTypes)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(plugin);
        Type type = null;

        foreach (Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
            if (t.GetInterface("IPlugin") != null)
                type = t;

        try
        {
            IPlugin loader = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            Plugins.Add(loader);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            LogWriter.Log("Could not load plugin.", e, LogFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to examine ExtractResults function, seems like something goes wrong there...

Comment: @Dusan - Thank you for your comment. I filled the method up with log posts, and know that everything runs as expected up to the return. I also examined the object that it was returning, which was created as it was supposed to be. However, just to be absolutely positive, I just sent a new object rather than getting it from the method, and that caused some unexpected errors. From that, I was able to track down the error to a SQL login issue in the OnProcessed method. Thank you again for your suggestion. If you create a reply, I would be happy to give you credit.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue, can you try tweaking the user account used by the service and see if that works?

Comment: Check "Allow service to interact with desktop" in the service and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the Receiver/Sender objects are not GCed? This may be the case, as your Initialization pattern for release and debug are different